# using indexed jobs in google kubernetes engine

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to run docker image on multiple data using [indexed jobs](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/04/19/introducing-indexed-jobs/).

It seems that indexed jobs is available since Kubernetes 1.21,
but my job on google kubernetes engine doesn't recognize the variable `$JOB_COMPLETION_INDEX`.

my yaml file looks like this:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - --job_id="$JOB_COMPLETION_INDEX"
```

If I set `job_id=0`, it works ok.

Even if I add the following in the top level spec,

```
spec:
  completions: 3
  parallelism: 3
  completionMode: Indexed
```

yaml file automatically remove the part (I'm using google cloud web console for editing yaml file).

I tried both `1.22.3-gke.700` and `1.21.5-gke.1302` with Kubernetes alpha features, but nothing worked.

Is indexed job available now in google kubernetes engine?

Answer (score 0):

where did you get `args`? Use `command` instead. It will be look something like this:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: 'sample-job'
spec:
  completions: 3
  parallelism: 3
  completionMode: Indexed
  template:
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
      - command:
        - 'bash'
        - '-c'
        - 'echo "My partition: ${JOB_COMPLETION_INDEX}"'
        image: 'docker.io/library/bash'
        name: 'sample-load'
```

It's from official documentation.

Or this example also works:

```
[...]
    spec:
      subdomain: my-job-svc
      containers:
      - name: task
        image: registry.example.com/processing-image
        command: ["./process",  "--index", "$JOB_COMPLETION_INDEX", "--hosts-pattern", "my-job-{{.id}}.my-job-svc"]
```